# Can't emit signal in QML custom Item

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots

I created my own Item with signal `clicked`, that contatins MouseArea. I want to emit signal `clicked`, when MouseArea is clicked. But nothing works.
Here is my .qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {

    id: baseButton

    property alias text: txt.text
    width: txt.width
    height: txt.height

    signal clicked

    onClicked : console.log("Clicked!")

    Text {
        id: txt
        color: "white"
        font.pointSize: 8
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mousearea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered: {
            txt.color = "yellow"
            txt.font.pointSize = 15
        }

        onExited: {
            txt.color = "white"
            txt.font.pointSize = 8
        }

        onClicked:  baseButton.clicked
    }
}
```

I'll be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions (which signals are) are first class objects in JS, so it is not an error to refer to them without parentheses.  But you need them in order to execute the function (i.e. emit the signal).

So just change this line:

```
onClicked:  baseButton.clicked()
```