# Cannot send/emit signal from QML custom Item

Tags: javascript, qml

I have following `QML Item`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item
{
    clip: true

    id: ueItemCategorySelector

    signal ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation()

    ListModel
    { 
      id: ueCategoriesModel
      ListElement {}
      ListElement {}
      ListElement {}
      ListElement {}
      function ueGetChildCategories () {}
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: ueCategorySelectorWrapper

        radius: 16

        gradient: Gradient
        {
            GradientStop
            {
                position: 0
                color: "#ffffff"
            }   // GradientStop

            GradientStop
            {
                position: 1
                color: "#000000"
            }   // GradientStop
        }   // Gradient

        border.color: "#4682b4"
        border.width: 1

        antialiasing: true

        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout
        {
            anchors.margins: parent.radius/2

            spacing: 0
            antialiasing: true

            anchors.fill: parent

            ListView
            {
                id: ueCategoryListView

                antialiasing: true

                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                clip: true

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter
                Layout.margins: 8

                spacing: 8

                highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true

                Component.onCompleted:
                {
                    model=ueCategoriesModel
                    //TODO once component is loaded, the first category must be selected (programmatically) to show products
                }   // Component.onCompleted

                delegate: Rectangle
                {
                    id: ueCategorySelectorDelegate

                    radius: 16

                    width: 256
                    height: ueCategoryListView.height-2*Layout.margins

                    clip: true

                    border.color: "#4682b4"

                    antialiasing: true

                    gradient: Gradient
                    {
                        GradientStop
                        {
                            position: 0
                            color: "#000000"

                            ParallelAnimation on color
                            {
                                id: ueCategorySelectorColorAnimation

                                loops: 1
                                running: false

                                ColorAnimation
                                {
                                    from: "#4682b4"
                                    to: "#000000"
                                    duration: 100
                                }   // ColorAnimation
                            }   // ParallelAnimation
                        }   // GradientStop

                        GradientStop
                        {
                            position: 1
                            color: "#ffffff"
                        }   // GradientStop
                    }   // Gradient

                    MouseArea
                    {
                        //id: ueCategorySelectorDelegateMouseArea

                        anchors.fill: parent

                        onClicked:
                        {
                            if(index!==ueCategoryListView.currentIndex)
                            {
                                ueCategoriesModel.ueGetChildCategories(ueCategoriesModel.get(index).ueRoleId);
                                ueCategorySelectorColorAnimation.running=true;
                                ueItemCategorySelector.ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation();
                            }   // if

                            ListView.currentIndex=ListView.index;
                        }   // onClicked
                    }   // MouseArea

                    ColumnLayout
                    {
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        antialiasing: true

                        spacing: 8

                        Image
                        {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: true
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop
                            Layout.topMargin: ueCategorySelectorWrapper.radius+4

                            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

                            horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

                            antialiasing: true
                            source: "image://ueCategoriesModel/"+model.ueRoleImage
                        }   // Image

                        Text
                        {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: true
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignBottom
                            Layout.bottomMargin: ueCategorySelectorWrapper.radius+4

                            color: "#000000"

                            text: model.ueRoleName
                            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                            font.family: "Courier"
                            textFormat: Text.RichText

                            font.bold: true
                            font.pointSize: 10

                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        }   // Text
                    }   // ColumnLayout
                }   // delegate
            }   // ListView
        }   // ColumnLayot
    }   // Rectangle
}   // Item
```

Now when I click on its `MouseArea`, the following QML runtime error pops up:

```
qrc:/gui/items/UeCategorySelector.qml:132: ReferenceError: ueItemCategorySelector is not defined
```

Why I cannot send/emit signal from `MouseArea`'s `JavaScript` code chunk?
I have tried solution from [Can't emit signal in QML custom Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108019/cant-emit-signal-in-qml-custom-item) but it does not work for me. I've added `id` to outer `Item` and I am now calling signal with

```
ueItemCategorySelector.ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation();
```

I do not understand now anything at all. If I change the code (change the order of statements) inside `onClicked` to

```
onClicked:
{
    if(index!==ueCategoryListView.currentIndex)
    {
        ueCategorySelectorColorAnimation.running=true;
        ueItemCategorySelector.ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation();
        ueCategoriesModel.ueGetChildCategories(ueCategoriesModel.get(index).ueRoleId);
    }   // if
}
```

then it works fine. Why?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo, did you delete your comments here, or were they removed by a mod?

Comment: I don't have this error on my PC, I use Qt 5.5 Linux, also you dont need to write `ueItemCategorySelector.ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation();` . `ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation();` is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code inside `onClicked` to:

```
onClicked:
{
    if(index!==ueCategoryListView.currentIndex)
    {
        ueCategorySelectorColorAnimation.running=true;
        ueItemCategorySelector.ueSignalStartProductSelectorAnimation();
        ueCategoriesModel.ueGetChildCategories(ueCategoriesModel.get(index).ueRoleId);
    }   // if
}
```

and now it works, but I do not have clue why.